# Extracting value from XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to write a SQL Server query to select values from a XML column.

The column `messagebody` (type `XML`) has content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GetActivityUnemploymentGenerelEventType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ActivityItem xmlns="http://service.bmuuuu/">
        <ActivityCoreItem xmlns="http://service.bmxxxx">
            <ActivityIdentifier xmlns="http://service.bmyyyy">d5ck7132-703c-1234-8099-963b35b24bc5</ActivityIdentifier>
            <StartDate xmlns="http://service.bmaaa">2016-01-25</StartDate>
```

I'm trying to nail the value of `startdate` and `ActivityIdentifier`.

I've tried several solution fx:

```
SELECT XML.query('messagebody(/GetActivityUnemploymentGenerelEventType/ActivityItem/ActivityCoreItem/ActivityIdentifier)')
FROM table

SELECT messagebody.value('(/GetActivityUnemploymentGenerelEventType/ActivityCoreItem/ActivityIdentifier/Value)[1]', 'int')
FROM table

SELECT messagebody.value('(/GetActivityUnemploymentGenerelEventType//ActivityCoreItem/ActivityIdentifier())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM table
```

Query result:

> Cannot find either column "messagebody" or the user-defined function or aggregate "messagebody.value", or the name is ambiguous.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You're not respecting the existing **XML namespaces** in your XML document! You need to include those in your XQuery - try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://service.bmuuuu/' AS ns1, 
                     'http://service.bmxxxx' AS ns2, 
                     'http://service.bmyyyy' as ns3, 
                     'http://service.bmaaa' as ns4)
SELECT
    ActivityIdentifier = xc.value('(ns3:ActivityIdentifier)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    StartDate = xc.value('(ns4:StartDate)[1]', 'varchar(25)')
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable
CROSS APPLY
    MessageBody.nodes('/GetActivityUnemploymentGenerelEventType/ns1:ActivityItem/ns2:ActivityCoreItem') AS XT(XC)
```

Comment: Hi marc_s
Thank you for taking time to answer me. Mayby i'm doing somthing wrong, but when I apply your solution, I get this error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CROSS'. Any ideas? But thanks againg - now I know a lot more.

Comment: @Dunkel: did you use your *actual* table name? I just used a *placeholder*, since I don't know what your table name is really called. `CROSS APPLY` was introduced in SQL Server **2005**, along with the `XML` datatype - so I assume you're using at least that version (or a newer one)

Comment: @Dunkel: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: Drive by OP user never showed up again but hey, I will up vote to do my part :)